# Get-AdGroupMember -recursive does not return groups when also returning users

Tags: powershell

I have been asked to audit access to a set of folders. Access is granted through a scheme where one AD group provides access ("Access Group") to the folder, while a second AD group (which is a member of the former) defines what users are granted that access. I want to export a list of both users and groups that are members or nested members of "Access Group".

I started out with

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Access Group"
```

This returned the groups and users that are members of that group. As the access scheme relies on nested groups, this didn't give me all I needed.

I next tried

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Access Group" -recursive
```

This only returned users that were members of the group.

I was expecting Get-ADGroupMember "Access Group" -recursive to return both users and groups that are members of the group.

In addition, when checking a set of nested groups that has no users as members, nothing is returned. As I understand [the documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps#parameters), empty groups should be returned:

> Specifies that the cmdlet get all members in the hierarchy of a group that do not contain child objects.
>
> If the specified group does not have any members, then nothing is returned.

I might be reading it wrong, but would like some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading it wrong:

> Specifies that the cmdlet get **all members in the hierarchy of a
>   group that do not contain child objects**

Groups contain child objects, therefore they aren't listed.

Comment: A group does not necessarily contain child objects, although it always has the ability to do so. On closer inspection, however, I see that the example for -recursive does not include groups, but only users.